# How would I mark that a cell value has been edited in a grid

Tags: tables, color, grid, edit

I have an excel like grid and I want to somehow mark what cell values have been edited (and changed back to normal after pressing the save button)

I was thinking about changing the number/background color, but what would be a good color?

Here is an image of the grid where the cell with 79 has been edited

[image: Grid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change to a different color, then we have to know to UI's color scheme so the use of color will be consistent.
You can also simply use bold since it really pops out when the rest of the data is in the regular font-weight and won't clash with other colors.
In short, in order for something to stand out, it must be more unique the the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your audience, I would suggest some icon indicator, asterisk, or perhaps bold font - possibly in addition to a different color.  Or a border style AND color around the changed fields.

Keep in mind that 1 in 12 men have some form of colorblindness, and 1 in 200 women do [[1]](http://www.colourblindawareness.org/colour-blindness/).

Depending on how accessible you want your app to be, and how important this feature is, then simply changing the color may not be the best option.

Some ideas for icons that might help indicate that a field has been changed would be a green checkmark, or perhaps even an undo arrow  (that when clicked would undo the change).